# Displaying a video as a background in Revaljs from Quarto presentation - is it possible to use an online source?

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I'm trying to display a gif from giphy.com as a background to a slide in Revealjs (compiles from Quarto document). Below is my code

```
## A bad workman? {background-video = "https://media.giphy.com/media/FaIDQOgN69FXq/giphy.gif"}
```

The background video does not play. Do I need to ensure that all video is local? I thought that it was possibly to pull in videos from sites like giphy, but I cannot seem to get this to work in Quarto. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, online source also works. But there are two things to note,

1. You need to use `background-image` for rendering `gif` file.
2. As I have also said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74139849/10858321), do not use space on either side of equal sign (i.e. =) when specifying background attributes. This is true for `background-image`, `background-color` or any other [Slide background attributes](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/index.html#slide-backgrounds).

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
---

## A bad workman? {background-image="https://media.giphy.com/media/FaIDQOgN69FXq/giphy.gif" background-size="contain"}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. I thought I'd tried this, i.e. without spaces, and using "background-image". What I've found is that sometimes preview fails, and I need to kill the process and start all over again. This could also have been the reason why I couldn't get this to work.