# How do you add a background image for the toc slide in revealjs Quarto

Tags: html, quarto, reveal.js

I have used the solution provided on  [Slide Background using images is not working in Quarto Reveal JS presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139381/slide-background-using-images-is-not-working-in-quarto-reveal-js-presentation/74139849?noredirect=1#comment136770150_74139849) to learn how to add slide background immages.

However, this solution doesn't work for toc (contents slide) since the toc slide is generated by yaml options and i dont see how to provide a background image for the toc slide.

I am using rtsudio and quarto.

**How do you add a background image for the toc slide in revealjs Quarto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use revealjs template partial [`toc-slide`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/revealjs/pandoc/toc-slide.html) to modify the TOC (Table of Contents) slide.

The `toc-slide.html` file initially looks like this,

```html
<section id="$idprefix$TOC">
<nav role="doc-toc"> 
$if(toc-title)$
<h2 id="$idprefix$toc-title">$toc-title$</h2>
$endif$
$table-of-contents$
</nav>
</section>
```

And, to add a background image to this slide, you just need to add an image file using `data-background-image` attribute in the `section` tag. Now you can create a YAML variable `toc-bg-image` in the quarto (`.qmd`) file to store the image link that you want to add as a bg image for the toc slide.

```yaml
---
title: "Backgrounds"
format: revealjs
toc: true
toc-bg-image: "https://picsum.photos/id/870/200/300?grayscale"
template-partials:
  - toc-slide.html
---

## Quarto {background-image="https://placeholder.pics/svg/500"}

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations see <https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.

## Bullets {background-color="red"}

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code
```

And then use that variable in the `toc-slide.html` template partial. **Note that the variable is wrapped within the `$` sign.**

```html
<section id="$idprefix$TOC" data-background-image="$toc-bg-image$">
<nav role="doc-toc"> 
$if(toc-title)$
<h2 id="$idprefix$toc-title">$toc-title$</h2>
$endif$
$table-of-contents$
</nav>
</section>
```

[image: A background image in the TOC slide]

Comment: Need use data-background-size="contain" in case the image is just not being fitted properly ot not visible. see next comment

Comment: editing the html like this worked:`<section id="$idprefix$TOC" data-background-image="$toc-bg-image$" data-background-size="contain">
<nav role="doc-toc">
$if(toc-title)$
<h2 id="$idprefix$toc-title">$toc-title$</h2>
$endif$
$table-of-contents$
</nav>
</section>`